# How to execute JMeter recorded script in parallel

Tags: jmeter

How can I execute those JMeter recorded script in parallel as we do while creating HTTP SAMPLER (Embedded HTTP Resource) ?
While recording I also checked Retrieve All Embedded Resource with pool of 6. Because of this I getting incorrect response time(Varies from browser timing of page).

Is there any way that we could execute our recorded HTTP Samplers in parallel?

Answer (score 1):

As of JMeter version 3.2 it is not possible to kick off extra threads to run a specific sampler(s) group in parallel, each thread (virtual user) executes samplers upside down.

So you should be very careful with what you are recording. For example, you must not be recording any embedded resources calls, there is `URLs Patterns to Exclude" input on the "Requests Filtering" tab of the [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) where you can define which resources need to be excluded from the recording.

[image: JMeter Recording suggested excludes]

Remember that well-behaved JMeter test should be producing response time similar to real browser, but you need to configure JMeter to mimic real browser, to wit:

- Add [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) to represent browser headers
- Add [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to represent browser cookies and deal with cookie-based authentication
- Add [HTTP Cache Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cache_Manager) to act like browser's memory and disk caches

See [How to make JMeter behave more like a real browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser) guide for more information on JMeter fine tuning.

Comment: If I exclude images, css, js and other urls using "URLs Patterns to Exclude" then it will reduce the response time but all these if being sent in browser as well So I think It will vary from response time of browser.

Comment: So Do you think @Dmitri, It will give response time as browser does

Comment: You **don't need to record** these requests, you need to tell JMeter to process them via `Retrieve All Embedded Resources from HTML Files` and `Use concurrent pool` options in the [HTTP Request Defaults](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request_Defaults). So JMeter will process "embedded" resources URLs from the main response in parallel just like real browsers do. See [Web Testing with JMeter: How To Properly Handle Embedded Resources in HTML Responses](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/web-testing-jmeter-how-properly-handle-embedded-resources-html-responses)

Comment: I tried that too. In order to do that I need to know how many request are being sent to the server. For example: Let say I need to do a shipment. Then I should know how many request are being sent to server while creating a shipment(There could be multiple requests in background). I think that would be more complex if I create each and every request manually.

Comment: As you are suggesting, It means we should do recording with excluding some urls(like css, images, js) and then add "embedded" resource call in each request. Does it make sense?

Comment: Yes, for "embedded" resources should be excluded during recording and handled via "Advanced" tab, and "external" resources should be excluded completely